# Python socket attributes

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I'm learning about Networking in Python and I was just wondering what do the attributes in the sockets mean.

If I run this:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print(sock)
```

The output is:

```
<socket.socket fd=1504, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
```

If I run it again, the attribute `fd` changes:

```
<socket.socket fd=1488, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
```

I want to know what do the attributes `fd` and `proto` mean, and why `fd` changes every time I run the code.

Thank you!

Comment: `fd` stands for file descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) comes from file descriptor. Every time you open a socket, you create a file to represent it, which has a different associated number.

Proto comes from protocol number, and it identifies the protocol used.